# Decryption on PHP have problems after 16 digits

Tags: php, encryption

I am doing AES encryption on ios End, and i the base64 encode that string and send over to php end. On the php end, i have following code:

```
<?php
$key = 'a16byteslongkey!';
$data = base64_decode('LsCH4nvvGPKN67v94Ig9BweQgOk9rtDdK7ZugeJkTS8=');
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = substr($data, 0, $iv_size);

function aes256_cbc_decrypt($key, $data, $iv) {
if(32 !== strlen($key)) $key = hash('SHA256', $key, true);
if(16 !== strlen($iv)) $iv = hash('MD5', $iv, true);
$data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
$padding = ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]);
return substr($data, 0, -$padding);
}

$result = aes256_cbc_decrypt($key,$data,$iv);
var_dump($result);

?>
```

But when i run this code i get this "anil.mnd@gmail.cA���u�"  . I should have got anil.mnd@gmail.com. I get only first 16 characters correct.

I am new to encryption so not have much idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

> I am new to encryption so not have much idea what is wrong.

If you're new and want something that "just works", use [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) instead of trying to write it yourself.

If you're up for the challenge, however, keep reading:

---

Your code is unreadable. Let's add some whitespace.

```
$key = 'a16byteslongkey!';
$data = base64_decode('LsCH4nvvGPKN67v94Ig9BweQgOk9rtDdK7ZugeJkTS8=');
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = substr($data, 0, $iv_size);

function aes256_cbc_decrypt($key, $data, $iv) 
{
    if (32 !== strlen($key)) {
        $key = hash('SHA256', $key, true);
    }
    if (16 !== strlen($iv)) {
        $iv = hash('MD5', $iv, true);
    }
    $data = mcrypt_decrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
        $key,
        $data, 
        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,
        $iv
    );
    $padding = ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]);
    return substr($data, 0, -$padding);
}

$result = aes256_cbc_decrypt($key,$data,$iv);
var_dump($result);
```

Specific problems:

- You're using `MCRYPT_MODE_ECB` for a function named `aes256_cbc` (have you seen [the penguin](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/)?)
- When I switch that out, I get [invalid data](https://3v4l.org/PDAAQ).
- Your encryption method is also probably broken, since [changing your IV to "\x00\x00"... makes it decrypt](https://3v4l.org/DqUbs).

Specific recommendations:

- Please, please, PLEASE consider [using well-studied cryptography code instead of writing it yourself](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it).
- `strlen()` and `substr()` are brittle. See: [function overloading](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php).
- Use a [real key derivation function](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-11-cryptographic-right-answers.html), not a hash function.
- Your IV (and keys, for that matter) should be generated from a [cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator, such as `random_bytes()`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/07/how-safely-generate-random-strings-and-integers-in-php).
- [Use authenticated encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).